# Testing accessibility on expo projects

Tags: xcode, accessibility, expo

So I have built an app in expo and I'm going to start doing things like accessibility testing. Is this possible in expo-cli? Do I have to convert to bare workflow to use any tools like XCode Accessibility Inspector? Or are there tools I can use with expo-cli? I have't been able to find any. I found this page, https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/accessibility/. But I was hoping for something more along the lines of the WAVE accessibility checker.